# DELETE not working without SELECT GRANT

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 Users in my MYSQL Database. `intra_read` granted with `SELECT` and `intra_write` granted with `DELETE`,`UPDATE` and `INSERT`. But unfortunately I can just delete a row with `intra_write` if I grant him `SELECT` aswell.

```
private function getphaseOutIDs($connection) {
    $sql = "SELECT Mitarb_ID FROM infoMail WHERE ref_date<NOW()";
    $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $statement->execute();
    return $erg = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

public function deletePhaseOutIDs($connectionWrite,$connectionRead) {
    while ($row = $this->getphaseOutIDs($connectionRead)) {
        $sql = "DELETE FROM infoMail WHERE Mitarb_ID=" . $row['Mitarb_ID'];
        $statment = $connectionWrite->prepare($sql);
        $statment->execute();
    }
}
```

Does someone know why this happens and could tell me how to fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: I believe SELECT is required before any other options can be allocated

Comment: select is basically read permission, so think if you dont provide read permission to a user how can he write or delete?

Comment: You are trying to select the record to delete with a WHERE clause. Now from the result of that statement (did it delete 1 row, or 0) I could possibly determine whether there was a record with that id in the table in the first place ... should I be able to do that without having the rights to read this table? No, of course not.

Comment: Actually WRITE works totally fine. I just can't use DELETE and UPDATE

edit: Thanks CBroe, that totally makes senses.

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't this:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM infoMail WHERE Mitarb_ID=" . $row['Mitarb_ID'];
```

Try this query:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM infoMail WHERE Mitarb_ID='". $row['Mitarb_ID'].'"";
```

Or

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM infoMail WHERE Mitarb_ID= {$row['Mitarb_ID']}";
```

Comment: Both way works.

Als i could write
{$sql = "DELETE FROM infoMail WHERE Mitarb_ID= {$row['Mitarb_ID']}";}